# Ag-Grid update rowdata from parent

Tags: angular, parent-child, ag-grid

I have two components, one where I got some selects (userType, user) and a button to add the selected user.

And another one with an ag-grid where I should display the users from the above component.

The reason why I have them into different components it's because my boss wants to reuse the first one in another part of the application, the grid I'm also going to used it with a similar component and asked me to do it this way.

I'm already passing the value at the beginning of the component, but I don't know how to detect when data has changed to refresh the grid.

parentComponent.HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <label>Reviewers are optional, select a review type and reviewer below to add to the submission 
        as reviewers</label>
    <div class="clr-row">
        <div class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-6 clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-xl-4">
            <clr-select-container>
                <label>Review Type</label>
                <select clrSelect name="reviewerTypes" (change)="onChange(currentReviewerType)" 
                    [(ngModel)]="currentReviewerType">
                    <option [value]="" selected disabled hidden>
                        Choose value
                    </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let reviewType of reviewerTypes" [ngValue]="reviewType">
                        {{reviewType.reviewType}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </clr-select-container>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-6 clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-xl-4">
            <clr-select-container>
                <label>Reviewer</label>
                <select clrSelect name="options" [(ngModel)]="currentReviewer">
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose value</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let reviewer of reviewers" [ngValue]="reviewer">
                        {{reviewer.user}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </clr-select-container>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-6 clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-xl-3">
            <clr-button-group class="btn-primary">
                <clr-button (click)="addReviewer()" >Add Reviewer</clr-button>
            </clr-button-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <app-q-sub-reviewer-grid style="width: 100%;" [reviewersAdded]='reviewersAdded'></app-q-sub- 
    reviewer-grid>
</div>
```

parentComponent.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.GetReviewerTypes().subscribe( response => this.reviewerTypes = response, error => 
   console.log(error));
   this.mockType = {id:1, reviewType:"type"}
   this.mockReviewer = {userId:1,user:"Samel"}
   //////////// this is a mock to see if it was working, i'll remove this lates
   let reviewerToAdd = {reviewerType:this.mockType, reviewer:this.mockReviewer}
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
}

onChange(selection){
   let reviewerId = selection;
   this.dataService.GetReviewersByType(reviewerId.id).subscribe( (response)=> {
     this.reviewers = response
     this.currentReviewer = response[0]
   }, 
   error => console.log(error));
}

addReviewer(){
   console.log(this.currentReviewer)
   let reviewerToAdd = {reviewerType:this.currentReviewerType, reviewer:this.currentReviewer}
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
   console.log(this.reviewersAdded)
}
```

childGridComponent.HTML:

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 118px;" class="ag-theme-balham" 
   [rowData]="rowData"
   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
   [animateRows]="true" 
   [enableSorting]="true" 
   [enableFilter]="true" 
   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
   (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

childGridComponent.ts

```
@Input('reviewersAdded') reviewersAdded: any[];

constructor() {
   this.columnDefs = [
     { headerName: "Review Type", sortable: true, filter: true, field: 'reviewerType', 
      suppressSizeToFit: false },
     { headerName: "Reviewer", sortable: true, filter: true, field: 'reviewer', suppressSizeToFit: 
      false }
   ]
   this.defaultColDef = { filter: true };
}

ngOnInit() {
}

onGridReady(params) {
   this.gridApi = params.api;
   this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
   this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
   this.reviewersAdded.forEach(item => {
   this.rowData.push({ reviewerType: item.reviewerType.reviewType, reviewer: item.reviewer.user })
      var res = this.gridApi.updateRowData({ add: [{ reviewerType: item.reviewerType.reviewType, 
      reviewer: item.reviewer.user }] });
      console.log(res);
   })
}

//////this ngOnChanges is not working
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   console.log(this.reviewersAdded)
}

onGridSizeChanged(params: GridSizeChangedEvent) {
   params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking the `ngOnChanges` is not getting fired because it is an array and array and objects are reference types. The `ngOnChanges` will only kick in when the location in memory of the array or object changes. So you have to modify the array immutably.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.GetReviewerTypes().subscribe( response => this.reviewerTypes = response, error => 
   console.log(error));
   this.mockType = {id:1, reviewType:"type"}
   this.mockReviewer = {userId:1,user:"Samel"}
   //////////// this is a mock to see if it was working, i'll remove this lates
   let reviewerToAdd = {reviewerType:this.mockType, reviewer:this.mockReviewer}
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
   this.reviewersAdded.push(reviewerToAdd)
   // have to spread the reviewerToAdd object as well since it's a reference type
   this.reviewersAdded = [...this.reviewersAdded, {...reviewerToAdd }];
}
....
addReviewer(){
   console.log(this.currentReviewer)
   let reviewerToAdd = {reviewerType:this.currentReviewerType, 
   reviewer:this.currentReviewer}
   this.reviewersAdded = [...this.reviewersAdded, { ...reviewerToAdd }];
   console.log(this.reviewersAdded)
}
```

With those changes, see if `ngOnChanges` activates.

If the `ngOnChanges` activates, you will need to update the row data maybe even by using `gridApi` or issuing another http requests and seeing if the data changes.

Comment: it's working the `ngOnChanges` now, I tried to update the `gridApi` but at the beginning, it throws me an error because it is `undefined`, also `this.reviewersAdded = [...this.reviewersAdded, { ...reviewerToAdd }];` this line duplicates the array, it adds the new reviewerToAdd plus the whole this.reviewersAddes again

Comment: So should there only be one? `reviewersAdded` should only be one. Then try `this.reviewersAdded = [...{reviewerToAdd}];`

Comment: no there should be many, but if I already have `{"ricardo", "alif"}` when I tried to add another one let's say tom, I get `{"ricardo", "alif", "ricardo", "alif", "tom"}`

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure, that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: sorry it was my fault haha now is working perfectly, no problem with that line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing Input Eventemitter in your code:

In your child (grid) component
define your dataSource or reviewrs property.

```
dataSource: any; // your reviewers that feeds the table.
get reviewersAdded() {
   return this.dataSource;
}

@Input() set reviewersAdded(val: any) {
    if (this.dataSource !== val) {
       this.dataSource = val; // update the datasource
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess rowData is equivalent to dataSource in the above solution